Как с помощью регулярного выражения при определенном событии заменять значение внутри скобок?
Есть строка str = 'Количество товаров () в данной категории'; в модальном окне, которая предполагает разные значения внутри круглых скобок () как-то (1),(15),(20) при выборе различных опций, т.е. с помощью регулярки мне нужно динамически менять значения (1),(15),(20).
Для этой цели я планирую проверять наличие внутри скобок значения или проверку на пустоту
let quantity = 5;
let str = 'Количество товаров () в данной категории';
str = srt.replace(/([\s]+|^$)/,quantity);

Но, в где-то я ошибся и не получаю запланированного результата


Но, в где-то я ошибся и не получаю запланированного результата

Предложу такой вариант...


const quantity = 5;
let str = 'Количество товаров () в данной категории';
str = str.replace(/(?<=\().*(?=\))/, quantity);
console.log(str)




Зачем стрелять пушкой по мухе? Регулярные выражения здесь совершенно не нужны и ни к месту. Правильно сделать так: для данного числа сделать отдельный тег, даже банально хоть span с id, и уже его использовать.
Написать document.querySelector('#my-number').textContent = 'xxx', гораздо проще в исполнении и уж тем более в понимании другими разработчиками что тут происходит

спасибо за совет, но в моём случае он не подойдёт, т.к.

других разработчиков не будет и за понимание я не беспокоюсь
затем стрелять, потому что str - это строка с переводом на разные языки и дробить на подстроки с учётом того, что ко всему прочему сайт представляет собой мультидоменную сеть, я не заинтересован.
Не усложнял описание вопроса, чтобы не уводить фокус в сторону иных решений

